# How can I name a color in a GIMP palette?

Tags: color, gimp, palette

Using GIMP 2.8.22 on Windows 10. I've created a new palette.  I add a color to the palette and now I want to name the color. I click on "undefined" but when I start typing it just triggers whatever tool shortcut is associated with the letter I'm typing.

I can even highlight the word "undefined" but still typing only trigger tool shortcuts. How can I name a color?

[image]

Comment: Seems like you have found a bug. I'm going to steal your description to file one in our bug tracker :)

Comment: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=785240

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher thanks for following up on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out. UI seems a little glitchy (from my perspective). As far as I can tell, by adding a second color to the palette and then selecting the first color the color title will switch from "undefined" to "untitled".  At this point I can then edit the color name.

Comment: You should accept your own answer as best answer if you have solved it.

Comment: @BillyKerr: I will but you can't until 2 days have passed.  Also I'm not sure it's the best answer, it's just _a_ answer. Could be a better one comes along

Comment: I get the same problem. So, like you I suspect a little glitch in the UI.  I did notice once you have added a second colour, you can then just delete it, and then it's possible to select and rename the first.

Comment: Not just  a glitch in the UI, if the palette is non-editable (standard palette) you get that behavior and there is no escape :)

Comment: <s>on 2.10.30, all the keys seem to swap the active tool in the toolbox, not type letters :(</s> edit: for some reason duplicating the pallet worked, can it not edit palettes in added palette folders?